# How to use "LIKE" in parameterized Cosmos query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using The Azure.Cosmos API, version 3.17.1.  If I run a query against my Cosmos collection as so, I get the results I expect:

```
string Sql = "SELECT c.LastName FROM c where c.LastName like 'Smi%'";
QueryDefinition oQry = new QueryDefinition(Sql);
FeedIterator<myObj> oFI = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<myObj>(oQry); // returns Smith, Smithers, etc.
```

If I try to parameterize this, I get nothing back:

```
string Sql = "SELECT c.LastName FROM c where c.LastName like '@KeyWord%'";
QueryDefinition oQry = new QueryDefinition(Sql);
oQry.WithParameter(@KeyWord, "Smi");
FeedIterator<myObj> oFI = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<myObj>(oQry);
```

Is this a syntax issue or something not supported?

Tks

Comment: Have you tried passing the full search string in as a parameter? That is, just have `@keyword` in your query, and then replace `@keyword` with a verbatim string like `@"Smi%"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `%` in your parameter names and don't need to  quote it.

Please try this code:

```
string Sql = "SELECT c.LastName FROM c where c.LastName like @KeyWord";
QueryDefinition oQry = new QueryDefinition(Sql);
oQry.WithParameter("@KeyWord", "Smi%");
FeedIterator<myObj> oFI =  container.GetItemQueryIterator<myObj>(oQry);
```